# If I create a web service using JAX-RS (on netbeans), it is essentially an API to the web service?

Tags: api, rest, soap, jax-rs

If I create a web service using JAX-RS (on netbeans), it is essentially an API to the web service?

The web service would be REST or SOAP based.
I realize that the API provides the interface to the web service's functions, but does JAX-RS expose the interface?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, include the library for JAX-RS depends of the Application Server.  If you use a application server in netbeans which is Java EE6 Certified, you don't need any additional libraries.

However, if you use netbeans and also Tomcat o a Java EE 5 server, netbeans automatically add the JAX-RS libraries, in this case, the reference implementation.

The user can also choose to do it by hand.

[image]

Read more:

- [Getting Started with RESTful Web Services](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html)
- [Developing RESTful Web Services with JAX-RS, Netbeans, Glassfish](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/caroljmcdonald/archive/2009/04/developing_rest.html)